# Debugging external executables using Visual studio 2013 professional

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

I need help on debugging with visual studio 2013. I've got professional VS2013 in my win7 64-bit machine.

I generated two executables: exec1.exe and exec2.exe for example.

My perl file invokes exec1.exe and exec1.exe invokes exec2.exe

perl file -> exec1.exe -> exec2.exe

Now, while running perl file some time later exec1.exe closes without any traces. As both of these executables are placed in some specific location in my project, I want to debug these files using visual studio debugger. Is there a way to debug these files using Visual studio?

If yes, please help me and post here.

Thanks & Regards,

Pankaj

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly you created exec1.exe and exec2.exe with Visual Studio?

If so, you can change them to call this (call it in the Main method):

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()
```

This way a popup is shown which will ask if you want to debug the code. Just press "Yes" and Visual Studio will start. Also put the exec1.pdb and exec2.pdb next to the executables (generated by visual studio). An example image of the popup is shown below. After pressing "Yes" you can debug the code.

edit: I incorrectly assumed it was .NET code, as Hans Passant points out, you should use  __debugbreak()

[image]

Comment: yes, you are correct that I generated these two executables using VS 2013.you said:   you can change them to call this (call it in the Main method):
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()       you mean that I should add this line in the main of both the executables? I'll keep the generated executables in some specific folder in my code other than the visual project location.

Comment: my application is in C. How to add this line System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()

Comment: Use __debugbreak().  Wait for the WER prompt, click the Debug button.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into .NET Reflector. It allows you to seamlessly debug into third-party code and assemblies, even if you don't have the source code for them.

Click [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/95789cdb-08f9-4dae-9b2f-fc45a452ad77) for the Visual Studio Extension.

It contains all the required instructions.